# How do I install 64-bit 16.04 version?

Tags: system-installation

It always defaults to 32bit. I'm totally new to ubuntu, but willing to learn this OS. Should have used it many years ago.....

Comment: What defaults to 32bit. Are you using a 64bit installation disk?

Comment: Why are you not starting with 18.04?

Comment: The architecture 32/64-bit depends on the ISO file you had downloaded. For 64-bit you need the amd64 iso ([link to download](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso))

Comment: just a FYI:  **amd64** means 64bit (*intel or amd*) **x86_64** and refers to the arch (or architecture). **i386/586/686** is the 32bit  **x86** (*intel or amd*) arch.  It's named amd64 for historical reasons (to separate it from the ia64 or intel's incompatible itanium (non-x86) cpu's)

Answer (score 0):

so as many people already commented check if you have the right version, cause if you have the 32-bit iso you can only install 32-bit. so please make sure you have the right iso file from the mainsite